# How to create multiple instances of a ViewModel based on the IEnumerable data object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a technician repository returning 8 results. I want to instantiate the ViewModel properties with those results. How can I achieve that ?

```
public class TechnicianViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public string GenerateName()
    {
        string str = GenerateURL();
        str = str + ".jpg";
        return str;
    }
    public string GenerateURL()
    {
        string phrase = string.Format("{0}", UserName);
        string str = phrase.ToLower();
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-");
        return str;
    }
}
```

The value returned by the data object contains the 8 results grouped as the technician model.

And the Technician Model looks like this.

```
   public class Technician
   {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Licensed { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Insured { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool DrugTested { get; set; }

    public string EducationalLevel { get; set; }

    public string Specialities { get; set; }

    public string Bio { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public bool IsFormerTech { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExperienceDate { get; set; }

    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Branch { get; set; }

    public DateTime ApprenticeshipStatusDate { get; set; }

    public string ActivityStatus { get; set; }

    public string ReviewURL { get; set; }
```

Edit:-

I have moved the query out of the constructor, now I will try to access it within the controller.

```
    public class TechnicianController : Controller
   {
    private readonly AADataContext aADataContext;
    private readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private readonly TechnicianViewModel TechnicianViewModel;


    public TechnicianController(AADataContext context)
    {
        aADataContext = context;
        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(aADataContext);
        var data = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Branch == "Calgary").Where(a => a.ActivityStatus == "Active");


    }
```

Comment: You can iterate throw collection and create instances of TechnicianViewModel and add to your list. To copy properties you can use automaper.

Comment: Can you show me how that is done, I am using IEnumerable Collection, how would a list help ?

Comment: What are you stuck on? You just map the needed properties `new TechnicianViewModel { Id = item.UserId, ... }`. You don't need an explicit loop either -- you can use a projection `data.Select(t => new TechnicianViewModel { Id = t.UserId, ... })`

Comment: @Jasen I was trying to do the following : `this.ID = item.UserId`.. but let me try that projection property, I am still new to this.

Comment: @Jasen ..Is it fine that I am doing all this within the constructor of the same View Model

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense. It looks like you are trying to assign a collection to a single instance. If you want a collection of TechnicianViewModels then move the query out of the constructor.

Comment: It might be helpful to sketch out the entities and what they're doing.  I'm trying to picture what you want the end result to look like.  Is the idea to have one page (one VM) that displays 8 rows with tech info?  If so, then the VM would have the properties for the page, including a collection of techs.  The Controller will get the techs and generate the VM, passing in the techs.  Then it passes that VM to the view.  In the view, you can iterate through the techs.

Comment: @Jasen I edited my question based on what you had commented, now can you take a look and advice on creating multiple instances of the `TechnicianViewModel`

Comment: @K_foxer9 I as actually able to do that without using a ViewModel, the reason for introducing a viewmodel was to get the selected technician's ID sent back via the view model rather than the querystring. So that I have clean URL.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest adding a ctor in the vm that takes a tech model and maps the few properties. Then, all you have to do is modify the data query and tack on after the last Where ... Select(a => new TechViewModel(a)); You might want to call ToList() before that select, though.

Comment: @K_foxer9 Can you give me a rundown on how that would look like, still new to all of this...

Comment: [@Jasen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46694740/2655263) is pretty much what I was suggesting, except for the ctor bit.  Same end result.

Comment: @K_foxer9 I was able to use Jasen's answer and solve the issue at hand. Now the main reason for me using a view model was to pass the ID of the selected Technician to the controller using a view model. Can you advice how I can achieve that without using `[HttpGet]`

Comment: @K_foxer9 Can you take a look at this :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695950/how-to-get-the-view-to-return-the-id-via-a-viewmodel-to-the-controller

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd argue the query doesn't belong in a view model. If you want a collection of your view model then move this query out of the constructor. You can do it in the controller action.

```
public ActionResult GetTechnicians(string branch, string status)
{
    var data = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetAll()
                   .Where(c => c.Branch == "Calgary")
                   .Where(a => a.ActivityStatus == "Active")
                   .Select(t => new TechnicianViewModel
                   {
                       Id = t.UserId,
                       UserName = t.UserName,
                       Bio = t.Bio
                   });
    ...
}
```

When you have a number of these or if you find yourself repeating this query move it to a new class.

```
public class TechnicianService
{
    private AADataContext context;

    public TechnicianService(AADataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TechnicianViewModel> GetTechnicians(string branch, string status)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this out, seems like a solution to my issue here

Comment: Ok this works, now how do I use this `TechnicianViewModel` to transfer the selected object back to the controller without the controller method being a [HttpGet] method. Because that is the whole reason why I introduced a View Model into the picture.

Comment: I appreciate all your assistance here. Thanks !

Comment: I left GET/POST out of the answer because it was unclear how you would use it. You can add `[HttpPost]` if you require that. Then change the string parameters to a `TechnicianViewModel` for the action signature.

Comment: This is what I am doing inside my view for someone to select a specific technician.So it is basically going to a different function within the controller. 
 `@Url.Action("Profile","Technician",new { url = item.GenerateURL() })`

Comment: An anchor will generate a GET request. And it sounds like a different problem. You should create a new question (if one doesn't already exist).

Comment: Ok let me write another question and probably you could help me out on it. Thanks

Comment: Checkout the question here :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695950/how-to-get-the-view-to-return-the-id-via-a-viewmodel-to-the-controller