# How to get the View to return the ID via a ViewModel to the controller?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have a view which returns an `IEnumerable` collection of Technicians via the `TechnicianViewModel`. The view model populates fine and displays the objects correctly.

However, at the moment I need someone to point me in the right direction with regards to selecting a specific technician.

If I was to click `More Info` on the technician, an `[HttpGet]` request would be initiated which would result in a queryString. And this is exactly what is against the requirements of this project.(Requirements of the project: no query string should appear in the URL)

Here is the view :-

```
  @model IEnumerable<ActionAugerMVC.ViewModels.TechnicianViewModel>
  <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="">
                           @item.UserName
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            Technician
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="~\imagesurl-@item.GenerateName()" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <p class="overlay__desc">
                           @item.Bio
                        </p>
                        <ul class="overlay__social">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-skype"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-whatsapp-outline"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Profile","Technician",new { url = item.GenerateURL() })" class="btn btn-accent">More info</a>


                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        }
        </div> <!-- / .row -->
```

Here is the View Model :-

```
 public class TechnicianViewModel
 {
 public Guid ID { get; set; }
 public string UserName { get; set; }
 public string Bio { get; set; }
 public string GenerateName()
 {
    string str = GenerateURL();
    str = str + ".jpg";
    return str;
 }
 public string GenerateURL()
 {
    string phrase = string.Format("{0}", UserName);
    string str = phrase.ToLower();
    str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-");
    return str;
 }
}
```

How can I avoid my controller method being an `[HttpGet]` as I had implemented here so that I can have the ID from the viewmodel object returned by the view.

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("technician/profile/calgary-{url}")]
    public IActionResult Profile(Guid? ID,string url)
    {
        var Profile = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetByGuidId(ID);
        return View(Profile);
    }
```

Comment: if you want to access model properties without sending them as a routevalue, you'll need to post the form with a submit element, or perform the submit via jquery.

Comment: @akerra So I have to change the `a` link which currently holds `Url.Action` to a form post button ?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend something like '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-accent">More info</input>' However you'll need some way of knowing which technician was selected, so you'll probably need to set the value of a hidden div to the id of the selected technician and bind that to a new model field

Comment: And that hidden div would probably map to the `TechnicianViewModel`'s ID property. Than I can use that ID to retrieve the entire object from the `Technician` Model

Comment: If I were doing it, I wouldn't use an IEnumerable<Model> but rather make the model contain a List<Technician> field and SelectedTechnicianId field (which would be the hidden div value)

Comment: @akerra Can you show me how you would do it, I am still learning and would be enlightened to learn better practices.

Comment: I will post as an answer. Give me a few.

Comment: is it acceptable to have their username in the routevalue? That would make things easier

Comment: I need the ID in the routevalue so that I can pull out their complete data from the database model.

Comment: oh it looks like you're saying in the question that is not allowed by the requirements.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the ID has to be passed but not via a GET request, because that will cause it to be appended to the Querystring.** So the requirement of the project is usage of Clean URLS.**

Comment: @UmarAftab then all your requests requiring an ID will have a temporary Id and redirected as akerra has shown, or you need to post all your requests that require an Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your View, change the link to the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Profile","Technician",new { id = item.ID.ToString() })" class="btn btn-accent">More info</a>
```

You can get rid of the HttpGet and Route decorators on your controller method. Those will be taken care of by the default routing config:

```
public ActionResult Profile(string id)
{
    TempData["guid"] = id;
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}

public ActionResult Profile()
{
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse(TempData["guid"]);
    var Profile = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetByGuidId(guid);
    return View(Profile);
}
```

Comment: Will that prevent the ID from appearing in the URL ?

Comment: Why do you not want the ID in the URL?

Comment: try the above which uses TempData to pass the guid along while cleansing the URL

Comment: Because thats what I have been asked by the manager to do. He does not want to see any question marks in the url. I adviced him that it does not affect google listing in anyway. However, this is my current situation and this is the requirement I have been asked to comply with.

Comment: if hes only worried about question marks, passing the id as a parameter won't add one, because it's a registered route configuration. The url would look like .../Technician/Profile/1233-12312-4322-4322-2342. But the edited answer I provided should look like .../Technician/Profile. Note I have not tested it.

Comment: If what you have provided works, I will definitely mark that as the answer. I will try it out.

Comment: The url of the pages come up as /Technician/Profile/1233-12312-4322-4322-2342 with the following error on the page :
`AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:`

Comment: Ok I figured that one out, but how can I keep the `[Route]` parameter as the url needs to show the technician's name.

Comment: you need to add username as a routevalue, and then edit the parameters of the controller method to match. If the username is unique, I'd suggest avoiding the redirect stuff and just find the technician based on username instead of guid (pass the username as the id instead of the guid, then create a TechnicianRepository.GetByUsername method).

Comment: Oh man, that is awesome. Thanks a lot @akerra , I do not know why I did not think of that before.